# Prefilter a SQL table with a Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have the following Trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG_Update]
   ON [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG]
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET  NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [DIENSTLEISTUNG] (BEZEICHNUNG, MENGENEINHEIT, 
        PREIS, BESCHREIBUNG, VORLAUFZEIT,
        AZ_MO, AZ_DI,AZ_MI,AZ_DO,AZ_FR,
        AZ_SA,AZ_SO,DIENSTLEISTUNGSART_ID,
        UPDATE_USER, UPDATE_DATE, RUESTZEIT,
        PERMISSIONS, KONTRAKTPOSITION,ARTIKELNUMMER,
        ANZAHL, BUCHUNGSHINWEIS, SONDERWUNSCH,FLAG)

    SELECT  BEZEICHNUNG, MENGENEINHEIT, 
        PREIS, BESCHREIBUNG, VORLAUFZEIT,
        AZ_MO, AZ_DI,AZ_MI,AZ_DO,AZ_FR,
        AZ_SA,AZ_SO,DIENSTLEISTUNGSART_ID,
        UPDATE_USER,GETDATE(),RUESTZEIT,
        PERMISSIONS, KONTRAKTPOSITION,ARTIKELNUMMER,
        ANZAHL, BUCHUNGSHINWEIS, SONDERWUNSCH,
        0 
    FROM INSERTED

    UPDATE  DIENSTLEISTUNG
    SET     DIENSTLEISTUNG.FLAG = 1 
    FROM    DIENSTLEISTUNG 
            INNER JOIN INSERTED
            ON INSERTED.ID = DIENSTLEISTUNG.ID            
SET NOCOUNT OFF;    
END
```

The Trigger copies an entire row with a new ID if a change in the original row happens. It also sets a FLAG in the new and old row (the old row gets FLAG = 1, the new row FLAG = 0).

Is it possible to filter these rows from within the Trigger so that it only returns the new rows with FLAG = 0?

If yes, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your trigger is not a "he" and it doesn't "return rows." I also don't understand the purpose of inserting flag = 0 and then updating it to 1 after the insert. Did you mean to perform the insert first, and set the flag to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are asking for is a Select trigger, then, NO, MS SQL Server does not support select triggers.

However, you could use a view that will return only those rows from the table where the `FLAG` column is 1, something like

```
create view dbo.DIENSTLEISTUNG_Flagged
as 
  select * from DIENSTLEISTUNG
  where FLAG=1
```

However, I would recommend having an extra table for the history records, instead just having them in-place. That way you could add additional fields, like a timestamp, or the user that changed the row, or the application that changed it, etc...
Something along the lines of (pseudo code for the trigger)

```
Insert into ServicesHistory (..., ChangeDate)
Select ... , getdate() from inserted
```

Note that this will also transform your 'instead of' trigger (pure evil) into a regular trigger (somewhat less evil)

Comment: Why are `INSTEAD OF` triggers pure evil?

Comment: @ypercube Triggers in general are often called evil, because they tend to do invisible side-effects, behind-the-back stuff, and thus are often hard to debug. `INSTEAD OF` triggers add to the mix that the side-effect is the only thing remaining, and in effect, the computer did not do what I explicitly instructed it to do.

Comment: While I don't like triggers (for the reasons you mention), I think that INSTEAD OF triggers are often used in SQL-Server, as there are no `BEFORE` triggers.

Comment: @SWeko I find your "pure evil" assertion quite a misleading and overly broad statement. Sometimes these are much better than a regular trigger. Why? Let's say I have a trigger on insert. I insert 1000 rows. Then my trigger realizes that the rows violate some business rule. Great, now we get to rollback. With an instead of trigger, we could have prevented all of that work, twice! I've used instead of triggers in several scenarios and find them quite worthwhile and useful (though, like after triggers and plenty of other features, they can be misused / misunderstood / under-appreciated).

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps you meant to update the existing rows first, *then* insert the new rows with a flag of 0.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG_Update]
ON [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET  NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE  d
  SET     FLAG = 1
  FROM    dbo.DIENSTLEISTUNG AS d
          INNER JOIN inserted AS i
          ON i.ID = d.ID;

  INSERT INTO dbo.[DIENSTLEISTUNG] 
  (
      BEZEICHNUNG, MENGENEINHEIT, 
      PREIS, BESCHREIBUNG, VORLAUFZEIT,
      AZ_MO, AZ_DI,AZ_MI,AZ_DO,AZ_FR,
      AZ_SA,AZ_SO,DIENSTLEISTUNGSART_ID,
      UPDATE_USER, UPDATE_DATE, RUESTZEIT,
      PERMISSIONS, KONTRAKTPOSITION,ARTIKELNUMMER,
      ANZAHL, BUCHUNGSHINWEIS, SONDERWUNSCH,FLAG
  )
  SELECT  BEZEICHNUNG, MENGENEINHEIT, 
      PREIS, BESCHREIBUNG, VORLAUFZEIT,
      AZ_MO, AZ_DI,AZ_MI,AZ_DO,AZ_FR,
      AZ_SA,AZ_SO,DIENSTLEISTUNGSART_ID,
      UPDATE_USER,GETDATE(),RUESTZEIT,
      PERMISSIONS, KONTRAKTPOSITION,ARTIKELNUMMER,
      ANZAHL, BUCHUNGSHINWEIS, SONDERWUNSCH, 0 
  FROM inserted;
END
```